# Issue with implementation of Extension of UIButton

Tags: ios, uibutton, swift2

I have a call button in multiple VCs which performs action of calling on same number. Instead of defining same func in each VC i decided to create extension of UIButton.

Need help , Not sure why am i facing issue but getting error at `target:self` saying `Expected parameter type following ':'`

Following is the code:-

```
extension UIButton {
    func callBtn(target:self)
    {
        let url = NSURL(string: "tel://1234567890")!
        UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL(url)
    }
}
```

**EDIT:**
Updated to mentioned solution:-

```
extension UIButton {
    func callBtn(target:UIButton)
    {
        let url = NSURL(string: "tel://1234567890)")!
        UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL(url)
    }
}
```

Inside Required VCs :- (Calling as follows)

```
callBtn.addTarget(self, action: #selector(callBtn.callBtn(_:)), forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)
```

Getting following error:-

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '- unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x15e8b330 '
```

Comment: How you tried to call this method!

Comment: actually i had added 3 parameters target, action and control. Was going to  call like `btn.addTarget(btn.callBtn)`

Comment: @Vishnuvardhan :- Following is how i called the method:-  `callBtn.addTarget(self, action: #selector(callBtn.callBtn(_:)), forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)` inside required VC

Comment: @EricAya That is my real code, only mobile number is changed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your code should be like,

```
extension UIButton {
func callBtn(target:UIButton)
{
    let url = NSURL(string: "tel://1234567890")!
    UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL(url)
}
}
```

Comment: Can you tell me why `self` isn't working ?. self and UIButton are same in this case as its used within an extension of UIButton.

Comment: Now, how to use that extension ?

Answer (score 1):

If you'll look at the error, it says an unrecognized selector has been sent to an instance. It is because the 'action' which you add in the `addTarget:` method of the button is supposed to be called on the `target`. Here you have given as `self` which is a object of type `UIViewController` and it does not have a method called `callBtn:`. So it wont recognize the the `callBtn:` method call. Instead change the extension from `UIButton` to `UIViewController` so that it implements the method. So whenever the button is tapped it will call your action method (`callBtn:`) on your target `self` which is a `UIViewController`.

```
extension UIViewController {
    func callBtn(sender: UIButton) {
        let url = NSURL(string: "tell://1234567890")!
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try using..

```
  extension UIButton {
        func callBtn(target:UIButton)
        {
            let url = NSURL(string: "tel://1234567890")!
            UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL(url)
        }
    }
```

Still you need any help feel free to ask me.

Comment: Now, how to use that extension ?